# How to store and index a typical TEXT field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do I store and index a typical TEXT field in MySQL. In my case the text field will have a max length of 500 Characters, I understand that beyond 255 Chars varchar will behave like a TEXT field, but I need the data to be indexed as well. I will be having where clauses to count certain type of string appearances in the field. Do I store it as TEXT and use a FULLTEXT on that or do I store it as a VARCHAR(500) and Index it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Full Text Indexing on MySQL requires the engine to be MyISAM.  Beyond that, I'd recommend using VARCHAR(500) rather than TEXT because:

- TEXT would allow more than 500 characters
- searching against VARCHAR is generally faster than TEXT, indexed or otherwise

Comment: when I do a show index on the table I see the Sub_part value for the corresponding column set to 333 when the field is VARCHAR(500), otherwise its NULL. will this cause problems in the queries?

Answer (score 0):

See [this awesome question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269557/is-it-a-correct-way-to-index-text-column-of-mysql-database) on generating fixed-length hashes for large fields.

Also, Consider building an index table with the "certain type[s] of string appearances", e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE main(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  long_text_field TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE main_string(
  main_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  main_string_types_ud INTEGER NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE main_string_types(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  certain_string VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

You can even user a `TRIGGER` statement to generate insertions for the index & association tables upon `INSERT` to `main`, but this will not be efficient.  At scale, you should populate that table at fixed time intervals, or async events.